# Nautilus pops up after suspend

Tags: 11.10, nautilus, suspend, sd-card

Every time I wake up my netbook with Ubuntu 11.10 after suspend, nautilus pops up to show me the contents of the SD card that is always plugged in just like I've just put it in. I set it to "do nothing" when an external storage device gets plugged in (which it obeys to) but it still pops up after suspend.

How do I disable this feature?

Comment: OP are you still looking for an answer? If so, you may need to repost your question as this is flagged for closure. Regards,

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.media-handling automount-open 'false'
```

But this will also break automatically opening Nautilus when you insert removable media.

Comment: Thanks you so much! That did it and I'm fine with the side effect. Nautilus is just a click away when I need it. Now I can use my netbook immediately after it wakes up instead of having to wait till Nautilus is finished mucking about which slows down the system tremendously. 
Thanks again!